# Alias not working in Debian

Tags: linux, debian

I've the following alias in `~/.bashrc`

```
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
```

But it still doesn't prompt me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you start a new bash session since changing the file? Did you make sure to load `~/.bashrc` (see the *INVOCATION* section in `man bash`; essentially, you need to run `bash -i`)

Comment: @DanielBeck I didn't start a new session, now I did :-) You can type this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @IMB: Instead of starting a new session, you can also execute `source ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files – `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` – aren't reloaded automatically after you save changes to them. `bash` doesn't monitor them for changes, they are only automatically evaluated during *bash invocation*.

After changing something, you need to explicitly load them. There are basically two ways:

- `source filename` or the equivalent `. filename` will evaluate `filename`'s contents in the current session. This is the easiest, if all you did was add or change existing definitions.
- Start a new `bash` session, optionally closing your current one. Depending on how your terminal emulator works, you might need to launch `bash -i` (for `.bashrc`) or `bash --login` (for `.bash_profile`) explicitly.

In modern, tabbed terminal emulators, this allows you to keep e.g. `vi .bashrc` open in one tab, edit and save repeatedly, while opening new tabs to test the results. In case you mess it up and the new tabs are not useable, you can also easily revert any changes.

For more information on these files and when bash evaluates them, see `man bash`'s section *INVOCATION*.